# Path connected component

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

I have the following Problem:

Let G be a topological group. We denote by G_0 the path connected component of the identity and by G'_0 the connected component of the identity

1. Show that G_0 is a normal subgroup and that two elements of G are in the same path-connected component if and only if they are in the same G_0 coset
2. same thing but now with G'_0

So i think I know how to do the proof that they are normal subgroups, but i'm strugling with

"that two elements of G are in the same path-connected component if and only if they are in the same G_0 coset"

I also know this definition:
"If H is a subgroup of G, two elements g_1 and g_2of G lie in the same (left) coset if g_1 = h*g_2 for some h in H."

I don't know how to start the proof , maybe someone has an idea/ hint for me ?
Thank you very much !

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: To answer your first question, you would like to show that $g,h$ are in the same path component if and only if $gG_0=hG_0$, but the latter condition is equivalent to $g^{-1}h\in G_0$ meaning that $g^{-1}h$ is in the path component of the identity. So given a path from $g$ to $h$, can you find a path from $\mathrm{id}$ to $g^{-1}h$, and vice versa?

Comment: So do i have to show something like id= g^{-1} * g=g^{−1} *h∈G_0 ? sorry i'm a bit lost after a long day ^^

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of a topological group where $G_0$ and $G'_0$ are even different? Maybe the point is moot.